# According to MVVM: are Services part of Model component or ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm

I would like to know if Services used in MVVM are part of a Model or ViewModel component.
I met with opinion that they are part of a Model since they are used as a way of extracting Model data.
Then they are used via Dependency Injetion in ViewModels.

Unfortunatelly I also met with opinion that they should be in same namespace as ViewModel.
Do you know good resources or any argument that could defend one one above opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of opinion and as such the question is likely to be closed. Having said that, your answer IMO is neither. Services should typically be contain in a `*.Services` namespace and separate from both. You may have a "Service" that lists the available Views and a separate service to list the available ViewModels. In addition, you may have a Service that does something completely different, not involving either Views or ViewModels. My advice is not to get hung up on this...

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer which met my expectations. Anyway if anybody will find any article, book reference I would be thankful because I would like to have even more arguments.